# discord.py - showing correct syntax of command whenever there is a MissingRequiredArgument error

Tags: python, error-handling, discord, discord.py

I have started developing a new discord bot. currently whenever there is an error i call the `on_command_error` function to send a message. Now, whenever there is a MissingRequiredArgument error I want the bot to show the error message AND the correct syntax of the command. Currently I have tried adding all of this manually, but is very time consuming and not worth it. I know discord.py can show command syntax since the default help command does that too.

So is there any way i can import the same logic over to my code?

Comment: There are a few differences between the help from the command line arguments and the call of a function. In general you should consult the [API documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) on a missing argument.

Comment: @KlausD. .Already tried looking the documentation. couldn't find anything helpful for this particular issue

Comment: What you presented is an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/781394). You are having an issue with a call, but instead of showing us the relevant code and the full error traceback you are asking for a kind of automated documentation system that could (possibly) give you documentation that already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some of [`commands.Command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20command#discord.ext.commands.Command) class attributes for this.
Looking at the documentation, this class has a `usage` attribute that you can set using the [`commands.command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20command#discord.ext.commands.command) decorator.

Let's say I want to make a round command:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

# Setting the command's name in the decorator to avoir overwriting the built-in round function
@bot.command(name='round', usage='3.14159265359')
async def _round(ctx, to_round: float):
    number = round(to_round, 1)
    await ctx.send(f'Rounded to one decimal: {number}')
```

If I send `!round e`, I would have the following error:

```
BadArgument: Converting to "float" failed for parameter "to_round"
```

But I can handle it, as you done, with [on_command_error](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        usage = f'{bot.command_prefix}{ctx.command.name} {ctx.command.usage}'
        await ctx.send('Failed converting an argument\nCorrect usage: {usage}')
```

Now, if I send `!round e`, the bot would send:

> Failed converting an argument
> Correct usage: !round 3.14159265359

Comment: Hey there. This does work! But only for BadArgument. I was looking for a solution for MissingRequiredArgument as stated in the title. Also you forgot to f-string the last line of `on_command_error` so it would print {usage} instead of what it needs to

Comment: Instead of `ctx.command.usage`, for MissingRequiredArgument use `ctx.command.signature`

Comment: You can use it for whatever error you want, I just gave an example so you could understand how to use it ^^' I also said that there was other attributes you could use.